# Link-analysis pattern search

Tags: algorithm, social-networking, graph-algorithm, graph-databases

**Problem Description**

I am implementing a link-analysis algorithm over a huge graph-database.

The graph database is constructed of entities (vertexes) and relationships (edges).

Each entity type has properties. For example *Person : [age,height,weight]*.

Each relationship has properties as well: For example *Call(Phone,Phone) : [date, duration]* or Own(Person, Phone) : [start-date, end-date].

Now, I am given pattern with the following structure:

*[entity-type,constrains] [relationship-type,constrains] [entity-type,constrains] [relationship-type,constrains] ... [entity-type,constrains]*

For example:

*[person,age>20] [own, start-date>1/1/2010] [phone, ends with '5'] [call date>1/1/2010] [phone, starts with '6'] [owned by, start-date<1/2/2011] [person, height>40]*.

I need to find ALL valid assignments for all the entities and relationships in the pattern.

I can query the database using the following primitives:

- Find first 1000 *[entity-type,relationship-type,entity-type]* assignments for a given set of constrains.
- Find next 1000 for the above
- Find first *[concrete-entity,relationship-type,entity-type]* assignments for a given set of constrains.
- Find next 1000 for the above

Keeping all the answers for a given query in the RAM is impossible.
There may be millions (billions?) of assignments to each entity-relationship-entity triple. However, the number of assignments for the whole pattern is assumed to be small.

**What I tried:**

For the chain *ET1-RT1-ET2-RT2-ET3-RT3*...
A naive implementation would be:

```
Get first 1000 (ET1-RT1-ET2)   
for each concrete ET2:
    Get first 1000 (ET2-RT2-ET3)
        for each concrete ET3:
            ...
```

The problem is that I may be solving the same sub-problems more than once.

I'm looking for a algorithm which eliminates such redundancies, that is also memory-efficient.

Note:

I'm looking for an algorithm. Not for an answer such as "Use SQL JOIN" / "Use SPARQL" ...

Comment: Not sure about an algorithm, but have you considered just memoizing the results of sub-problems.

Comment: look at map reduce; I wish I had a good link for you

Comment: @Gerrat: I'm afraid a naive lookup-table would be too large. I need something more sophisticated here.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic programming should be helpful here.

Let us simplify the rules as R1-R2-R3...Rk here.

Let next_nodes(node x, Rule R) return all the nodes linked x that is in compliance with rule R. If R is a entity constraint: it return a singleton set of same node if condition is satisfied, else a empty set. For relational constraint, it returns all the linked nodes that satisfy the condition.

```
Initialize cur_set to all set of nodes.

nextset = {}

For each rule R in Ri:
    for each node x in cur_set:
        nextset = nextset U next_nodes(x)
    cur_set = nextset
```

You should be able to store the set as hashtable or a tree (any log(n) search and update time data structure).

Although I have omitted the part where you keep the path of the traversal, it should be pretty easy to do. For each element in the set add an attribute called 'path' and append the current node at every iteration. Note that multiple paths might lead to same intermediary/final node.

Comment: This method will only store paths for which the conditions were satisfied. It will reevaluate failed paths (which are most of the paths). It may also requires a huge temporal storage.

Comment: @LiorKogan You want only paths that satisfy the conditions right? It will not reevaluate failed paths (Each condition is tested on a node at most once). Yes, it does require large space.